Can't use round method inside Double extension in Swift
I have the following code and it works:
func roundVal(_ val: Double) -> Double {
    round(revenue * 100) / 100
}

Now I want to move this code into Double extension:
extension Double {
   func roundedVal() -> Double {
       round(self * 100) / 100
   }
}

It fails because the first round and the second one are different:

global round func
inner mutating round func

And the problem is Swift forbids calling mutating func from a non-mutating one even if I create a local func variable (which is mutable). How to resolve this issue correctly?
